# How to do substring search in elastic search?

Tags: python, python-3.x, elasticsearch

I am trying to do elastic search to do a substring search.

```
response = es.search(index='salary_fulltime', body={
        'query':{
            'bool':{
                'must':[{
                        'match_phrase':{
                            'title':'sr. java developer'
                        }
                    },{
                        'match_phrase':{
                            'location':'holtsville'
                        }
                    }]
            }
        }
    })
```

In my database I have titles like,

```
Senior Java Developer, Java Developer, Java Engineer
```

But don't have examples like `sr. java developer` etc.,

Is there a way I can do the sub-string match. Even though I don't have `Sr.` in my elastic search index, is there a way to match `sr. java developer` with what's in our database like `Senior Java Developer, Java Developer, Java Engineer`.

Currently my search doesn't match anything.

```
[{'_id': '484',
 '_index': 'data',
 '_score': 13.8527,
 '_source': {'title': 'Java Developer / Engineer'},
 '_type': '_doc'},
{'_id': '385',
 '_index': 'data',
 '_score': 12.527,
 '_source': {'title': 'Senior Java Developer / Engineer'},
 '_type': '_doc'},
{'_id': '433',
 '_index': 'data',
 '_score': 11.828527,
 '_source': {'title': 'Java Architect'},
 '_type': '_doc'}]
```

Comment: How about using `match` instead of `match_phrase`? Or maybe add `slop` to match_phrase? https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-slop-with-phrase-search-in-elasticsearch-6

Comment: Can you tell me a bit about `slop` in `match_phrase`? Can you explain a bit about how to use it?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the `title` field is of `text` data type. So, if no analyzer is defined for `text` data type fields, then elasticsearch uses a [standard analyzer](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html). This will tokenize `"Senior Java Developer"` into

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "senior",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 6,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "java",
      "start_offset": 7,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "developer",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 21,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

In the search query when you search for `sr. java developer`, this again gets tokenized into `sr`, `java`, `developer`. This query will match any document that has any of the above tokens.

You can simply use [`match`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query.html) query instead of match phrase query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": "sr. java developer"
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67660379",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6409958,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Java Developer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67660379",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5403744,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Senior Java Developer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67660379",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "3",
        "_score": 0.14181954,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Java Engineer"
        }
      }
    ]
```

**Update 1:**

You can use the `minimum_should_match` parameter with the match query

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "title": {
        "query": "sr. java developer",
        "minimum_should_match": "75%"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "67660379",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "2",
        "_score": 0.6409958,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Java Developer"
        }
      },
      {
        "_index": "67660379",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 0.5403744,
        "_source": {
          "title": "Senior Java Developer"
        }
      }
    ]
```

Comment: I can't use match due to some conditions. If I use match I am getting lot of stupid results. For example if I search for `'lero developer'` I am getting values like `Web Developer`. But if I use match_phrase I am not getting such invalid results. When I check scores for me I am getting values like `8.828527` or `11.16` not in the scale of 0-100%

Comment: Is there anyway I can getting scores in range of `0-100`% so I can choose which ones to choose.

Comment: @user_12 so when you search for `sr. java developer`, what do you expect to get? (based on the sample data you gave in the question above)

Comment: I just need it to match with java developer and senior java developer etc., with scores in the range of 0 - 100% but currently I am not getting scores in those range. If I can get it matches 60% with java develop I can select those. But now I am getting scores like 11.8 or 8.3 or 4.4 etc., How are you getting scores in 0 - 1 range?

Comment: @user_12 the score depends on various factors, like the number of documents, frequency of term, length of the field.  You can use this explain API, to know more about how the score is calculated in your data (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html). And, since I have indexed only 3 documents in the index, my score would definitely be lower than yours

Comment: Is there any way I can get it in percentage, for example I can write a condition like match only the original title if the match percentage /similarity is 85% etc., Is that possible?

Comment: @user_12 Yes, it is possible. Please go through the updated part of the answer, and let me know if this resolves your issue ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232771/discussion-between-user-12-and-escoder).